# Accessing file outside document root - am able to zip - not able to display

Tags: php, apache, file, path

I have some images saved separately in folder outside the document root.

I  write a program  to zip those images using  `ZipArchive();`

the php file is running inside sub folders of my document root.

i just give the outside image path as an array and pass it to zip object and works fine

```
$imgList = array(
    '/OUTSIDEFOLDER/img1.jpg',
     '/OUTSIDEFOLDER/img2.jpg'
);
```

same path i used to display the image in

```
<img src='/OUTSIDEFOLDER/img1.jpg'>
```

this is not working. What i am doing wrong . Is it a limitation of image source or

i have to look any config htaccess settings

Comment: These are absolute paths, so naturally PHP can access them on the filesystem. The src attribute requires relative or full URLs so that the browser can dowload the images.

Answer (score 2):

The document root specifies what parts of your server's file system is available to be served up by the webserver.

If you could just specify any path you wanted, anyone could steal anyfile they wanted from your server, etc..

To serve something from outside the document root, you'll have to

1. create an Apache [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) that points to the file, so it effectively becomes "inside the document" root
2. Create a filesystem symlink inside your document root that points to the external file, and make sure the webserver allows such symlinks and follows them
3. Use a script (e.g. php) to serve up the file.